# Can my iOS App load a XML file and Generate Interface from the information within XML?

Tags: ios, xml

I'm working on a home automation project. Here's what I want to do:

- The app starts and it'll have a button to load an XML file.
- The XML will have information about the rooms in the house like "Living Room, Dining Room, Kitchen etc.". It'll also have information about the equipment, like "Home Theater, TV, Blu-Ray Player, etc. in this case with a relation with the room that they belong" and so on with IR, RS-232 cmds, etc.
- I'll install this app in different houses, so I intend just to change the XML file as the house changes.
- I intend to generate the UI from the information contained in the XML file. E.g. The house has only "Living Room and Dining Room". The tab bar will show only those two tabs.

So, my questions:

- Will Apple reject my app?
- Can my customers just download the app from the App Store, and change and load the XML file? I mean, there's a package in the .app file, is it possible to open it and change the .xml file inside it?
- Is it possible to change the UI as the XML information changes?

---

EDIT: more questions:

@competent_tech is saying that dynamic generation of code isn't allowed, but I'll change the code within the .storyboard or .xib .nib files, isn't it?

About the Contacts: I think is a little bit different idea, because in the contacts app, e.g.: there are 10 fields to fill out, like first name, last name, e-mail, phone number, etc. As a user, if I don't fill out the e-mail field, it'll still be there anyway. My plan is kind of different:

- The house has 2 equipments to control: - Tab bar with item 1 and item 2.
- The house has 3 equipments to control: - Tab bar with item 1 and item 2 and item 3.

Do you still think this is possible?

Can you recommend a book about this? I couldn't find anything useful myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, only apple can answer the rejection question.

However, from what you have described, there shouldn't be an issue since this is configuration-based changes instead of code changes. Apple specifically prohibits download of code and dynamic generation of code.

You can liken it to Contacts: iOS doesn't come configured with contacts, they allow you add them and configure different things about them. This sounds very much like what you are doing.

You should be able to download an XML file from a website or web service and use that to configure the app. We use a web service to retrieve data into the local Sqlite database to configure nomenclature and UI component visibility based on the current user and it works quite nicely.

Comment: That's excellent news! Keep in mind that if an answer solves or helps you solve your question, you should click on the checkmark and up arrow next to the answer to let future visitors to this question know that this is the answer that helped you.

Comment: OK, but I still don't have enough reputation to check the up arrow...lol... I'll do it later.

Comment: Thanks! Did you mean to check the first answer or this one?

Comment: @competent_tech i need to generate ODK library for ios. in that xml which will come from server and we need to parse it to generate whole ui of the app. on the very initial base app will have 2 or 3 screens but further screens and flow will be decided after xml parsing. so will it be approved by apple ?  Your help will be very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

With `generating code` they mean executable code, not the generating of views or viewcontrollers. If that is forbidden too, you could distribute your app via addhoc, but you need one developer program per 99 clients.